# Nested menu with parameters in Symfony and KNPmenu

Tags: symfony, knpmenu

I am struggling with Symfony2 and Knpmenu to build a menu that handles:

- breadcrumbs
- routing with dynamic parameters
- rendering of separate menus starting with different children

My `Menu/Builder.php` file looks like this (the extra bits like navbar, pull-nav etc are part of the mopa_bootstrap extension that handles the rendering using bootstrap classes):

```
namespace My\AppBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;

class Builder
{
    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem(
            'root', array(
                'navbar' => true,
                'pull-right' => true,
            )
        );

        // Main Menu -> Config
        // no link here, it's just a placeholder
        $dropdown = $menu->addChild(
            'Config', array(
                'dropdown' => true,
                'caret' => true,
            )
        );

        // Menu -> Config -> User
        $dropdown2 = $dropdown ->addChild(
            'User', array(
                'route' => 'user',
            )
        );

        // Secondary Menu -> Edit (but child of Menu -> Config -> User)
        $dropdown2->addChild(
            'Edit',
            array(
                'route' => 'user_edit',
                'routeParameters' => array('name' => $options['id']),
            )
        );
```

The idea is to have a main menu that prints the first two levels only, and a separate menu that gets rendered somewhere else to allow users moving between the edit/delete/whatever views of that specific element being viewed.

What I am trying to achieve, is to have a single structure thus to handle the parenting structure, not only to have sign parents as active in the menu, but also to be able to handle a working breadcrumb structure.

In`Resources/views/base.html.twig` I am calling the main menu like this:

```
{{ mopa_bootstrap_menu('MyAppBundle:Builder:mainMenu', {depth: 2}) }}
```

And ideally the sub menu like this:

```
{% set id = app.request.attributes.get('id') %}
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') starts with 'user_' %}
    {% set menu = knp_menu_get('MyAppBundle:Builder:mainMenu', ['User'], {'id': id }) %}
    {{ knp_menu_render(menu) }}
{% endif %}
```

However:

1. knpmenu returns error when rendering the main menu, as `$options['id']` isn't defined
2. I still can't render the secondary menu (therefore by passing the parameter 'User') - the page just returns a black output in that block

Is this approach correct?
I'm using `"knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev"` and `"symfony/symfony": "2.5.*"`

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, using [this method](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/menu_builder_service.rst) allowed to access effectively `$request` and add the conditional in the `MenuBuilder.php` file to prompt the sub-sub-items only under certain conditions.

The final code looks like this:

```
// Menu/MenuBuilder.php

namespace My\AppBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MenuBuilder
{
    private $factory;

    /**
     * @param FactoryInterface $factory
     */
    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function createMainMenu(Request $request)
    {
        $menu = $this->factory->createItem(
            'root', array(
                'navbar' => true,
                'pull-right' => true,
            )
        );

    // Main Menu -> Config
    // no link here, it's just a placeholder
    $dropdown = $menu->addChild(
        'Config', array(
            'dropdown' => true,
            'caret' => true,
        )
    );

    // Menu -> Config -> User
    $dropdown2 = $dropdown ->addChild(
        'User', array(
            'route' => 'user',
        )
    );

    // Secondary Menu -> Edit (but child of Menu -> Config -> User)
    // Skip this part if we are not in the relevant page, thus to avoid errors
    if (false !== strpos($request->get('_route'), 'user_') && $request->get('id')):
    $dropdown2->addChild(
        'Edit',
        array(
            'route' => 'user_edit',
            'routeParameters' => array('id' => $request->get('id')),
        )
    );
    endif;
```

And the services configuration file:

```
// Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    my_app.menu_builder:
        class: My\AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]

    my_app.menu.main:
        class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
        factory_service: my_app.menu_builder
        factory_method: createMainMenu
        arguments: ["@request"]
        scope: request
        tags:
            - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main }
```

And then the `Resources/views/base.html.twig` template:

```
// Main menu
{% set menu = knp_menu_get('main', ['Config', 'Users'], {'id': id }) %}
{{ knp_menu_render(menu) }}

// Secondary menu
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') starts with 'user_' %}
    {% set menu = knp_menu_get('main', ['Config', 'Users'], {'id': id }) %}
    {{ mopa_bootstrap_menu(menu, {'automenu': 'navbar'}) }}
{% endif %}
```

The solution seems to work, but if you have a better approach please do let me know!